# Completely cover a $2$D surface with circles of UNEQUAL size?

Tags: algorithms, circles

I have a mapping problem I'm looking for an algorithm for. There's the common problem of covering a surface with circles of equal sizes, but what about UNEQUAL sizes? Where circle size depends on where it's placed? Suppose you have a raster grid where the cell value determines the radius of the circle if the center were to be placed there. How would you determine where to place circles? The goals being complete coverage, fewest circles, and minimal circle overlap.

Comment: What does "cell value" mean? How does that determine circle radius? Can you give an example to illustrate what you are trying to do?

Comment: It sounds like the problem won't ever be solvable for certain "rasters", e.g. if every cell value is smaller than the radius required to reach the neighboring cell.

Comment: yes, the condition is that resolution < minimum cell value